# Error when library receives the FILE pointer and read the file

Tags: c++, file, shared-libraries

The function read a matrix from a file, and print it on the screen. but there is something wrong when library `fscanf(fp, "%u", &elem);` read file from fp.

It's OK when I change `uint8_t elem` to `uint8_t *elem` .

I want to know why! What should pay attention when program transfers a FILE pointer to the library. Thx!

main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    Matrix8g mat;
    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen("mat.dat","r")) == NULL){
        printf("can't open the file");
    }
    //matrix with 24 rows and 11 cols
    mat.Make_from_file(fp, 24, 11);

    //print the matrix
    mat.Print();
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Part of library file (Make_from_file):

```
/* Set the matrix from a file */
int Matrix8g::Make_from_file(FILE *fp, int rows, int cols){
    int i, j;
    uint8_t elem;

    this->rr = rows;
    this->cc = cols;
    Resize_matrix();

    try{
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                fscanf(fp, "%u", &elem);
                Set(i, j, elem);
            }
        }
    }catch(...){
        NOTE("Error when set the matrix from a file");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at this reference [c reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/)

You would see that fscanf needs a reference to the data structure to which the extracted date should be written. fscanf copies from the given file/stream to the given pointer. It has no information about what type the data has. It uses the format string to interpret the byte from the input. Its similar to a type casting. fscanf can't know which type is needed as target structure but a pointer allows a straight copy operation.

Comment: Yes, I misused fscanf, I change <code> uint8_t elem </code> to <code>unsigned int elem</code> and it is OK now.